# mapping spark dataframe datatypes to jdbc datatype

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I am using `df.write.jdbc` to save a dataframe to a database table.

One of the columns in my dataframe is a of type `map(string, string)`. How do I write this into a database table? The target is a redshift database.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to serialize the map to a string or probably make json out of it and then save it.